# how do I use res.render with mongoose find function?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a route that gets all of the clients in mongodb and returns them. When I try to use `res.render()` from with the mongoose find() callback, I get an error saying that `ReferenceError: res is not defined`

Here's the code that works and that I've confirmed is returning the clients:

```
app.get( '/clients', function( request, response ) {
    return ClientModel.find( function( err, clients ) {
        if( !err ) {
            return response.send( clients );
        } else {
            return console.log( err );
        }
    });
});
```

Here's the code that I'm trying to use to render the ejs view, while passing it a list of clients:

```
app.get( '/clients', function( request, response ) {
    return ClientModel.find( function( err, clients ) {
        if( !err ) {
            res.render('clients/clients.ejs', {
              clients: clients
            });
        } else {
            return console.log( err );
        }
    });
});
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `response.render` instead of `res.render`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It will work.

```
app.get( '/clients', function( request, response ) {
return ClientModel.find( function( err, clients ) {
    if( !err ) {
        response.render('clients/clients.ejs', {
          clients: clients
        });
    } else {
        return console.log( err );
    }
}); 
});
```